# Lyon cost of living

Tags: france, cost-of-living

I am trying to research the cost of living in Lyon, France and I am looking for estimates of what is the approximate minimum net income that is required for a young non-French-speaking couple to allow a safe and decent life?  What about a young couple with a small child?

What can one expect to spend on the basics, i.e. rent, utilities, food?

Comment: The question has already garnered two “close” votes (not from me) for being “primarily opinion-based”. It might be useful to provide more details on your expectations and focus it on one aspect (say rent) to make it more objective.

Comment: This is pretty broad, unfortunately.  There's a strong likelihood it'll get closed as 'too broad' or 'subjective', but I'll try and answer objectively below.

Comment: What is safe and decent life? For example, you expect to have a roof and bad, wash every week and eat bread with some cheese, or have at least 3 rooms, bathroom with hot water, shower every day, and eat 3 full meals a day, at least one with meat?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, this is going to vary a LOT from couple to couple, and depending on the area in Lyon. Similarly, what you're used to may be very different to another couple. Apartment vs house, etc.

Possibly the most objective measure is to use a site like [Expatistan](http://www.expatistan.com/).

For example, if you were moving from [Sydney, Australia, to Lyon, France](http://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living/comparison/sydney/lyon), you can use that link and see that the cost of living is considerably less for food, housing, clothing and entertainment, but personal care costs will increase.

So for you, it'll depend a lot on what you spend on each category, whether you'll notice it. And where you're from, of course.